# Dynamic object creation of an array of pointers

Tags: c++

I try to create objects dynamically. Each object is a pointer in an array of pointers. The compiler gives me

```
error C4700: uninitialized local variable 'villages' used.
```

And I can not figure out how to fix it. I would be very grateful to all the helpers.

```
    int villageAmount;
    cout << "Defining villages:\n\nEnter how many villages do you want: ";
    cin >> villageAmount;
    Village **villages;
    for (int i = 0; i < villageAmount; i++)
    {
        cout << "\nDefining village's details #" << i + 1 << ":\n";
        villages[i] = new (nothrow) Village;
    }
```

Comment: Is this what you want to do? `villages = new Village*[villageAmount]` ?

Comment: `villages` is never assigned storage, so `villages[i]` points Crom-knows where. It needs something like `villages = new Village *[villageAmount];` But instead save youeself a LOT of pain and suffering and read up on [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: @user4581301 -- who is Crom?  Never heard that one before.  <g>

Comment: Recommended reading: [Why should C++ programmers minimize use of 'new'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new)

Comment: What about `std::vector<>` and why do you need pointers? Can't you just use normal objects and place them in the container?

Answer (score 3):

```
Village **villages;
```

you declared `villages` without initializing, so it contains garabage valaue.

```
for (int i = 0; i < villageAmount; i++)
{
    cout << "\nDefining village's details #" << i + 1 << ":\n";
    villages[i] = new (nothrow) Village;
}
```

right below, you access into it and writes. That's no no.

If you want to store pointer of village (i.e. type of `Village*`) dynamically, you also need to allocate them.

```
Village **villages = new Village*[villageAmount];
```

Or if amount is fixed,

```
Village *villages[10] = { nullptr, }; // 10, 12344, or whatever
```

Answer (score 1):

villages memory is never allocated, you should use a vector or any sort of container (an array look fine here).
If you really want to allow the memory manually you could do something like :

```
Village **villages = new Village*[villageAmount];
```

Don't forget to free EVERY new, (If you only free villages, all the Village* that he contain will remain allocated.

Edit : someone else answered so I guess my answere is usless

Comment: why are you using `new` for an array and not `new[]` instead? `Village **villages = new Village*[villageAmount]; ... delete[] villages;`

Comment: Yes mybad, I was doing some C so I was still using malloc syntax